# Dealing with lost connection insert

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a SQLite database which will store all the data entry on an Android application. It will then check if it has a Network Connection - If it does it will send a JSON post to a Restful web service.

I was going to do it straight to the web service and then save it in the SQLite database if there was no connection , but what if connection is lost half way through the transfer?

What should I do if I lose Network Connection? My suggestion on this would be the following

- Insert data into SQLite Database to store data
- Check the connection every 5mins. (What if the user gets a connection in between, and then inserts the data?)
- If they have a connection - get the SQLite database results, check them against the MySQL database, and insert any fields that do not exists? (Maybe put a flag in the database to see if it has been posted)

Is this a good way of doing it? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the use of some sort of queue in your Android application which will hold requests against your web service until they are completed successfully.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)

Comment: Ok - I didn't think of doing it that way. Do I store the JSON Object into the queue? what if the user exits the application?

Comment: You could put the json objects in the queue, and have a method running on a timer that (a) pulls stuff out of the queue, and (b) sends it to your web service -- transactionally is best, which means if the web service call fails, then the item stays in the queue.  If the user exits the application, AND the queue writes to storage, it'll just pick up again once the application is started again.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Just a question, I create a Worker Thread that keeps trying until it has a connection. If it has a connection, send the JSON Object to the MySQL database? 

So there no real need to store the data in a SQLite database? Im better off just fetching all the data, incase the application goes offline and just store the insert in a queue?

Comment: You're on the right track.  The queue is more or less a technology sitting ***on top*** of a database (sometimes mysql!).  You could use just the mysql database, if that's all it's for.  But you want to wrap the process that mirrors to the web service ***within a MYSQL transaction*** so that if the web service call fails, your application knows to retry later.  If you don't wrap in a transaction you have less of a guarantee that you'll be keeping things in sync.  The server side will have to have something that can filter out duplicate requests (which may be rare, but can happen).

Comment: How would I pass that information back if the MySQL transaction failed to the application? Sorry about the hundred questions. Does it not return the status 200?

Comment: Use something simple - return some json with a result code, i.e. 0 = error, 1 = updated, 2 = duplicate (ignore?).

    {result : 0, message : 'Unable to write because of blahblahblah'}

Comment: Thank you! Ive got it now. :)